# Calculating the forcing factor for CH4, O3L and O3S

Tags: climate, climate-models

I have estimated the emissions (NOx, CO and HC) from a certain route, hence this is a list with emissions in grams per minute. Now I want to give some idea on the climate impact, so use the thesis from Emily Schwartz Dallara (2011) with the title "Aircraft Design for Reduced Climate Impact", chapter 5.

I want to use the following formulas:

CH4 and O3L
[image]

H2O and O3S
[image]

Both formulas require the forcing factor, which is defined as:
[image]

Here I have my problem: I need to know the RF of CH4, O3L and O3S (for this forcing factor) but I have no clue how to determine this. I cannot find it in the thesis either.

Can someone help me with obtaining this information? Again: I have the NOx, CO and HC emissions with the corresponding altitudes.

The thesis can be found here:
https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:yf499mg3300/thesis_online_final-augmented.pdf